# How to mock ResponseEntity

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Please find below mentioned code :
I need help to write `Mockito` condition for `ResponseEntity`:

```
if(isObjectPresent(ePartnerRestRequestDTO)) 
{

        ePartnerRestRequestDTO.setLoggerId(loggerId);
        String url = new StringBuilder(EPARTNER_MICRO_SERVICE_URL).append(service).toString();
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<String>(prePreocess(ePartnerRestRequestDTO), HttpMethod.POST, new URI(url));

        Instant before = Instant.now();
        ResponseEntity<String> response =  new RestTemplate().exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
        logger.info("ePartner service " + url + " - duration (milliseconds) :: " + Duration.between(before, Instant.now()).toMillis());

        if(isObjectPresent(response) && isObjectPresent(response.getStatusCode()) &&  HttpStatus.OK == response.getStatusCode()) {
            ePartnerRestResponseDTO = postProcess(JWSResponseUtil.verifyJWSSignatureAndExtractPayload(response.getBody()));

            if(isObjectPresent(ePartnerRestResponseDTO) && isValuePresent(ePartnerRestResponseDTO.getResponseCode())) {

                if(SUCCESS_CODE.equals(ePartnerRestResponseDTO.getResponseCode())) {
                    status = true;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock creation of NEW object with vanilla Mockito.

**1)** I would advise moving the creation of the object to a package level method:

```
RequestEntity<String> getRequestEntity(/* params */){
   return new RequestEntity<String>(prePreocess(ePartnerRestRequestDTO), 
        HttpMethod.POST, new URI(url))
}
```

**2)** and then spying on the class under test

```
@Spy
private ClassUnderTest classUnderTestSpy;

@Before
public void init(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    doReturn(myPreparedRequestEntity).when(classUnderTestSpy).getRequestEntity(/* params*/);
}
```